# Can an enum have a constructors for each of its constants

Tags: java, constructor, enums, effective-java

Please look at this [link](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=RhXmBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA154). In his book Effective Java, Joshua Bloch says

Note that the Operation constants are put into the stringToEnum map from a
static block that runs after the constants have been created.

> Trying to make **each constant put** itself into the map from **its own**
>   constructor would cause a compilation error

. This is a good thing, because it would cause a NullPointerException
if it were legal.

> Enum constructors aren’t permitted to access the **enum’s static fields**,
>   except for **compile-time constant fields.**

This restriction is necessary
because these static fields have not yet been initialized when the constructors run.

I have two questions

1. Can Enums have separate constructors for each constant?
2. Why are compile time constant fields accessible in constructors but not static fields?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add code example for those who can't access it from your link?

Comment: @Pshemo, Yes Sir, This link contains whole Item 30 from Joshua Bloch's book Effective Java https://ly2xxx.wordpress.com/page/5/?app-download=ios

Comment: I meant to put it directly in question. Links tend to break so when it happens your question will be useless for future readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for first question: you cannot have separate constructors, but you can work-around this in the following manner:

```
public enum EnumTest {
    ONE() {
        void init() {
            val = 2;
        }
    },
    TWO() {
        void init() {
            val = 1;
        }
    };

    protected int val;

    abstract void init();

    EnumTest() {
        init();
    }
}
```

This way you technically have separate initialization methods for different constants.

Another way is to use initializer sections:

```
public enum EnumTest {
    ONE() {{
            val = 2;
        }},
    TWO() {{
            val = 1;
        }};

    protected int val;
}
```

As for your second question: constant fields are not accessible during enum construction, because enum constants are accessible for static fields. For example, this code compiles correctly:

```
public enum EnumTest {
    ONE, TWO;

    public static final String ONE_STRING = ONE.toString();
}
```

If accessing ONE_STRING from the constructor were allowed, you would either had an endless initialization loop or accessing of not-yet-initialized enum constant.

Answer (score 4):

1. No, and I don't think that is what Bloch means, although it has not been formulated in the best possible way. An `enum` can have constructors, as the `enum Operation` in the book has. What Bloch means with "its own constructor" is: when the constructor of `Operation` runs for that particular constant.
2. This is already answered by what you quoted above:

   > This restriction is necessary because these static fields have not yet been initialized when the constructors run.

Comment: So sorry I can accept only one answer. But I'll upvote your other answers to increase your numbers by +25

Answer (score 3):

The regular rules for constructors apply.  You can have as many constructors as you want so long as they have different signatures.  Different `enum` values can then be built using different constructors:

```
enum StringAndNumber {
    Zero("zero"),
    Five(5),
    Pi("Pi", 3.14159);

    private final String str;
    private final Number num;

    private StringAndNumber(String str) {
        this.str = str;
        this.num = null;
    }

    private StringAndNumber(Number num) {
        this.num = num;
        this.str = null;
    }       

    private StringAndNumber(String str, Number num) {
        this.str = str;
        this.num = num;
    }
}
```

Comment: So sorry I can accept only one answer. But I'll upvote your other answers to increase your numbers by +25